# c++ Data Structure Pyramid user defined data structure in cpp using class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class pyramid{

private:
    int count;
    void* Data;
    pyramid* Right;
    pyramid* Left;
    pyramid* Up;
    pyramid* Down;

 public:

    pyramid(void){
        this->Data=0;
        this->count=0;
        this->Up=NULL;
        this->Down=NULL;
        this->Left=NULL;
        this->Right=NULL;

    }
    bool isPyramidFull(){
        if(this->Up != NULL )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    bool isPyramidEmpty(){
    if(this->Up == NULL )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    void insertData(){}//stuck at this point how to set data using 
    //VOID POINTER
    void deleteData(){}//stuck at this point how to set data using 
    //VOID POINTER

};


int main() {

    pyramid p;
    p.insertData();
    p.deleteData();

    return 0;
}
```

i am beginner in cpp and also in Data structure designing my own DS.
seeking help and guidance in proper way to implement mine DS like 
PYRAMID at top layer of three (1->at face we can see 2-> left to face 3-> 
right to face but left to face->left->left) and just bottom again layer of three (three times 1->face 2->left 3->left->left) i want a ds to hold all kind of data in void pointer also root is just one ds is just like PYRAMID
at top most prioritisation data to be held as we move down pyramid data goes increases and priority decreases as move down ds holds lots of data at bottom also inside pyramid more secure data can be stored so can move right left up down and also holds data in void poiter to make code more generic.

Comment: I don't understand your question. But I have a few remarks regarding your code: don't use void-pointers to store data. This is C++. Use a template parameter to define your payload type-safe. Your methods isPyramidFull and *Empty are not well designed. It's enough to say "return this->Up" in isPyramidFull. You should also get rid of the "Pyramid" in "isPyramidFull" because it's superflous - you are on a pyramid. isPyramidEmpty should just be "return !isFull()".  Both methods should be const. Your methods "insertData","deleteData" are also badly named. You don't do either. You just set a pointer

Comment: Your nameing-conventions for variable names is inconsistent. It's sometimes capitalised, sometimes not.

Comment: Its in camel case then why its still inconsistent

Comment: no it's not. count is lower-case. If you were conistent, it would be Count.

Comment: You have variable names like `p` `Data` `count` `Right`. Typename is lowercase as well. Probably function names can be lowercase as well with such approach.

Comment: This question is completely unclear. What is a pyramid structure ?  How can you insert data without providing anything ?  What are the relation of one pyramid to the others you point to ?  How do you add those relationships ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you're looking to add user supplied `Data` which is of type `void*`. I assume this `Data` will not be an array but a single value. To do this you would do (this isn't tested):

```
pyramid::~pyramid()
{
  delete Data;
}

void insertData(void* data, unsigned int size)
{
  delete Data; // Clear out any existing memory.
  Data = reinterpret_cast<void*>(new unsigned char[size]); //Allocate memory.
  std::memcpy(Data, data, size);  // copy user 'data' to 'Data'.
}
```

You would then use your code as follows:

```
void main()
{
  pyramid p;
  int some_data = 10;

  p.insertData(static_cast<void*>(&some_data), sizeof(some_data));
}
```

#### Better Approach

Use templates since it will eliminate problems associated with copying unknown memory and allocation. Also, please be consistent with naming. Remember, other people will have to read your code.

```
template <typename T>
class Pyramid
{
private:
    int count;
    T data; // No need for pointer since data structure should hold its own data.
    Pyramid* right;
    Pyramid* left;
    Pyramid* up;
    Pyramid* down;

 public:

    Pyramid()
      : count(0), right(nullptr), left(nullptr), up(nullptr), down(nullptr)
    {}

    bool isPyramidFull() { return up != nullptr; }

    bool isPyramidEmpty() { return up == nullptr; }

    void insertData(T dataItem) { data = dataItem; }

    void deleteData()
    {
       // This whole Pyramid class should be deleted which means you'll
       // have to reconnect the left, right, up and down pointers manually.
    }

};
```

To use this new template form do the following:

```
void main()
{
  Pyramid<int> p;
  p.insertData(10);
}
```

#### Conclusion

You need to better define how this data structure should act. The function `insertData` should sort itself and adjust `right`, `left`, etc so you have an organized data structure. Because I do not know what you are trying to do with `Pyramid` I cannot help beyond this.